# Apache CXF: A SOAP 1.2 message is not valid when sent to a SOAP 1.1 only endpoint

Tags: java, web-services, soap, cxf

first of all, I know that there are already some questions on SO about this topic but none of them solved my problem (or I am too stupid to understand them, that's a possibility as well).

So, I have a WSDL. From the WSDL I've generated a Java client using Eclipse CXF plugin. Now I'm doing this:

```
JaxWsProxyFactoryBean factory = new JaxWsProxyFactoryBean();
factory.setServiceClass(MyServiceInterface.class);
factory.setAddress("myEndpoint");
List<Interceptor<? extends Message>> interceptors = new ArrayList<Interceptor<? extends Message>>();
interceptors.add(new HeaderOutInterceptor());
factory.setOutInterceptors(interceptors);

MyServiceInterface service = (MyServiceInterface) factory.create();
```

The interceptor only adds an header to the requests I'm sending through the client:

```
message.put(Message.CONTENT_TYPE, "application/soap+xml");
```

I'm adding this manually since by default the content type is text/xml and I get a 415 error.

The problem is that with this configuration I get this exception:

```
org.apache.cxf.binding.soap.SoapFault: A SOAP 1.2 message is not valid when sent to a SOAP 1.1 only endpoint.
at org.apache.cxf.binding.soap.interceptor.ReadHeadersInterceptor.handleMessage(ReadHeadersInterceptor.java:178)
at org.apache.cxf.binding.soap.interceptor.ReadHeadersInterceptor.handleMessage(ReadHeadersInterceptor.java:69)
at org.apache.cxf.phase.PhaseInterceptorChain.doIntercept(PhaseInterceptorChain.java:308)
```

I've tried adding this annotation to the generated client interface:

```
@BindingType(javax.xml.ws.soap.SOAPBinding.SOAP12HTTP_BINDING)
```

But nothing changed. Can anybody help me?

**EDIT**

I've added a cxf.xml file under the classpath. This is the content:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:jaxws="http://cxf.apache.org/jaxws"
xmlns:soap="http://cxf.apache.org/bindings/soap"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans 
       http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-2.0.xsd
       http://cxf.apache.org/bindings/soap 
       http://cxf.apache.org/schemas/configuration/soap.xsd
       http://cxf.apache.org/jaxws 
       http://cxf.apache.org/schemas/jaxws.xsd">

<jaxws:endpoint serviceName="ClabService" endpointName="ClabServicePort">
    <jaxws:binding>
        <soap:soapBinding version="1.2" mtomEnabled="true" />
    </jaxws:binding>
</jaxws:endpoint>

</beans>
```

However, now I get this exception:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.RuntimeException: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'org.apache.cxf.jaxws.EndpointImpl---51955260': Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is javax.xml.ws.WebServiceException: org.apache.cxf.service.factory.ServiceConstructionException: serviceClass must be set to a valid service interface or class
```

I've tried to add this during the factory configuration:

```
factory.setServiceClass(MyServiceInterface_Service.class);
```

but nothing changed.

Comment: Need more clarification on this. What is the end point you are trying to hit?

Comment: The endpoint works fine, if I use SOAP UI I get a correct response back. I think the problem is that CXF is generating a SOAP 1.1 client meanwhile the server response is 1.2.

Comment: if you are getting namespace as `SOAP_NAMESPACE = "http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope"`. You are on soap 1.2. you can check that once? Exception says otherwise.

Comment: I'm not sure how to check that on CXF but using SOAP UI I get that namespace back.

Comment: `@BindingType(javax.xml.ws.soap.SOAPBinding.SOAP12HTTP_BINDING)` doesn't work for me when I tried putting this on my client. I changed the version from xml like `<jaxws:binding>
    <soap:soapBinding version="1.2" mtomEnabled="true" />
  </jaxws:binding>`. you can try changing the version through xml instead of annotation. I fee the problem is you are not not able to set cxf soap version to 1.2.

Comment: Ok, but I don't have an xml configuration since I'm not using Spring. Can I do that anyway? If so, how? I've only found spring tutorials. Thank you!

Comment: Follow this post to change soap version http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4248098/cxf-how-to-set-soapversion-on-cxf-port-without-spring

Comment: I've already tried what that question says (the annotation comes from there) without success. I've updated the question with my most recent tries. Thank you.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You can use JaxWsClientFactoryBean to create client. It will have option to setBinding to Soap 1.2.

```
JaxWsClientFactoryBean factory = new JaxWsClientFactoryBean();
factory.setServiceClass(MyServiceInterface.class);
factory.setAddress("myEndpoint");
List<Interceptor<? extends Message>> interceptors = new ArrayList<Interceptor<? extends Message>>();
interceptors.add(new HeaderOutInterceptor());
factory.setOutInterceptors(interceptors);
factory.setBindingId("http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap/bindings/HTTP/");//soap 1.2
MyServiceInterface service = (MyServiceInterface) factory.create();
```

Comment: Adding this line worked for me: `factory.setBindingId("http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap/bindings/HTTP/");`

Comment: Available bindings can be found in the `javax.xml.ws.soap.SOAPBinding` interface

Answer (score 5):

[geg](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2805265/geg) already said it, I just want to make it more visible:

```
import javax.xml.ws.soap.SOAPBinding;
...
factory.setBindingId(SOAPBinding.SOAP12HTTP_BINDING);
```

Comment: Do you provide a complete example of this please?  I'm trying to change the SOAP port but with no luck. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50141966/set-cxf-soap-version-to-1-2

Comment: Use the code from the accepted answer above (https://stackoverflow.com/a/39405537/332788) and then add the line `factory.setBindingId(SOAPBinding.SOAP12HTTP_BINDING);` before `MyServiceInterface service = (MyServiceInterface) factory.create();`

Comment: Wait, I looked again, he already has that line, only he didn't used the constant `factory.setBindingId("http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap/bindings/HTTP/");//soap 1.2`

Comment: Adding this line fixed issue for my client application.